# Package node.js in Cocoa/OSX app

Tags: javascript, objective-c, node.js, macos, cocoa

OK, here's what:

- **I don't want** to write an OSX app in node.js - the app is almost complete and 100% in Objective-C/Cocoa
- **I don't want** to bridge Objective-C and node.js
- **I want** to be able to execute a js/node.js script, regardless of whether the user has already pre-installed the node.js binary

So, is there any known way? What would you suggest?

Comment: Isn't that just a matter of embedding the binary inside of the app package and calling it?

Comment: @borrrden Is it? I mean: *is is that simple*? a) Have you tried this specifically with Node.js and got it working (in the range of OSX 10.7->10.10), b) Have you published an App Store app like that?

Comment: I haven't tried it with node.js specifically, but it was easy enough to do with other binaries that I'd created (not submitted to the App Store but I can't imagine it would be a problem).  Perhaps you could be more specific about where you are actually having trouble?

Comment: @Dr.Kameleon, did you ever get this working, packaging and using node.js inside an OS X app?

Comment: @Brett What can I say. I'm still struggling. These days I've been doing all sorts of experiments (with Node WebKit, Atom's Electron, and everything). They're not bad. But there's still something missing - not to mention that doing all that and keeping the app AppStore-friendly is close to impossible. I really don't know... :S

Answer (score 0):

I found a couple resources that look as though they have had success embedding node in a Mac App.  I haven't tried them yet, but they look promising.

[How to add NodeJS and node_modules to a Mac App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23403586/how-to-add-nodejs-and-node-modules-to-a-mac-app)

https://ind.ie/labs/blog/gracefully-running-node-as-an-nstask-in-cocoa/

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [zeit/pkg](https://github.com/zeit/pkg): Package your Node.js project into an executable.